# VS Code Suggesting Wrong Snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two snippets in VS Code. One of them has a prefix of `dprn` and the other has a prefix of `ddump`.

The problem I'm running into is that when I use one of these snippets a few times in a row, VS Code will always put that snippet at the top of the suggestion list.

Here's an example: I use the `ddump` snippet three times in a row and then I try to use the `dprn` snippet. The top suggestion in the window is `ddump`. This even happens when I type `dprn` all the way out.

[Here is an image to clarify the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjUN2.png)

What I'm looking for is a setting of some kind that I can use to override the suggestions when I type a snippet's prefix out all the way.

My current solution (which isn't ideal but works) is to make sure that all of my snippets start with different letters.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this setting and see if it helps:

> // Controls how suggestions are pre-selected when showing the suggest
>   list.
>   //  - first: Always select the first suggestion.
>   //  -
>   recentlyUsed: Select recent suggestions unless further typing selects
>   one, e.g. `console.| -> console.log` because `log` has been completed
>   recently.
>   //  - recentlyUsedByPrefix: Select suggestions based on
>   previous prefixes that have completed those suggestions, e.g. `co ->> console` and `con -> const`.

```
"editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed"
```

Perhaps `recentlyUsedByPrefix` is the option you need?

Comment: That really sounds like it's exactly what I need. But, unfortunately, it does not work.